# CRC implementing a specific polynomial. How does the polynomial relate to the polynomial used in code?

Tags: c, crc

I have the following CRC function:

```
#define CRC8INIT    0x00
#define CRC8POLY    0x18              //0X18 = X^8+X^5+X^4+X^0

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

uint8_t crc8 (uint8_t *data, uint16_t number_of_bytes_in_data)
{
    uint8_t  crc;
    uint16_t loop_count;
    uint8_t  bit_counter;
    uint8_t  b;
    uint8_t  feedback_bit;

    crc = CRC8INIT;

    for (loop_count = 0; loop_count != number_of_bytes_in_data; loop_count++) {
        b = data[loop_count];
        bit_counter = 8;

        do {
            feedback_bit = (crc ^ b) & 0x01;

            if (feedback_bit == 0x01) {
                crc = crc ^ CRC8POLY;
            }

            crc = (crc >> 1) & 0x7F;

            if (feedback_bit == 0x01) {
                crc = crc | 0x80;
            }

            b = b >> 1;
            bit_counter--;

        } while (bit_counter > 0);
    }

    return crc;
}
```

How does 0x18 relate to the polynomial X^8+X^5+X^4+X^0?

X^8+X^5+X^4+X^0 = 100110001

0x18 = 00011000

What if I define CRC8POLY as 0xEA instead (I have seen this), what polynomial would that represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does 0x18 relate to the polynomial X^8+X^5+X^4+X^0?

Since the code is a right shifting CRC, the "most significant bit" of each byte is bit 0 instead of bit 7. The poly needs to be reversed from 100110001 to 100011001, which is 0x119, after the right shift, bit 0 of 0x119 is shifted off, so 0x118 can be used instead. The code uses a second if statement to or in (0x100) >> 1 == 0x80 if the feedback bit is 1. As an alternative, since feedback_bit is 0 or 1, then (0-feeback_bit) can be used as a mask (assuming two's complement math) for the poly instead of using an if statement.

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
#define CRC8INIT 0x00
#define CRC8POLY 0x8c   // 0x119 >> 1

uint8_t crc8 (uint8_t *data, uint16_t number_of_bytes_in_data)
{
    uint8_t  crc;
    uint16_t loop_count;
    uint8_t  bit_counter;
    uint8_t  b;
    uint8_t  feedback_bit;

    crc = CRC8INIT;

    for (loop_count = 0; loop_count != number_of_bytes_in_data; loop_count++) {
        b = data[loop_count];
        bit_counter = 8;
        do {
            feedback_bit = (crc ^ b) & 0x01;
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ ((0-feedback_bit) & CRC8POLY);
            b = b >> 1;
            bit_counter--;
        } while (bit_counter > 0);
    }

    return crc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That CRC code is written rather oddly, where the polynomial is applied in two different places, breaking up the bits. That is, at `crc = crc ^ CRCPOLY` and conditionally `crc = crc | 0x80`. It would normally be written more like this:

```
unsigned crc8(unsigned char const *dat, size_t len) {
    unsigned crc = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc ^= dat[i];
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8c : crc >> 1;
    }
    return crc;
}
```

where `0x8c` is that polynomial reversed, without the x<sup>8</sup> term.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [Wiki article on CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) , it's crc8 realization as used in Dallas 1-wire chips. Note, that polinomial can be represented in Normal, Reversed, Reciprocal and Reversed reciprocal representations (see also [Polynomial representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks#Polynomial_representations)). Seems, that it is Reversed reciprocal representation with highest bit omitted.