# How do I model CRC for this protocol

Tags: crc

I have a protocol spec sheet for a TWI device which states:

> The CRC bytes are an eight bit cyclic redundancy check using an
> initial seed of 0x5A and a polynomial XOR value of 0x18.

The spec gives some example commands:

[image]
and also later an additional example with CRC 0x07 resulting from Command 0x15

It also states

> Data are sent bit-serially with the most significant bit first.

I tried to calculate CRC values for the command examples given using http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

[image]

playing with reflected and non-reflected inputs and results, but I can't get the calculated CRC to match the command examples.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

The CRC is reflected, and the polynomial is x<sup>8</sup>+x<sup>5</sup>+x<sup>4</sup>+1. That polynomial reflected with the high power dropped is `0x8c`. This C code calculates the CRC:

```
unsigned crc8twi(unsigned char const *data, size_t len) {
    unsigned crc = 0x5a;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc ^= data[i];
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8c : crc >> 1;
    }
    return crc;
}
```

That gives the CRC `06` for `0c`, `48` for `0c f0 64 b8 13`, `5a` for `11 03`, `a5` for `00`, and `07` for `15`.

I don't know how to get the `48` in the second example, but I also have no clue what the up and down arrows mean, nor what the blue and pink colors mean.

I also have no idea what is meant by the "polynomial XOR value of 0x18". The Koopman representation of the correct polynomial would `0x98`, which is close but not the same.

*Update:*

Ok, the `0x18` comes from a truly tortuous approach to the CRC calculation, as shown in this example from a link in the OP's comment below:

[image: tortuous assembly code]

In that example the application of the polynomial occurs in two different places. The `0x18` is the polynomial shifted down by one, though not reflected since the code trudges through the data bits one at a time.

This was in fact noted in [another answer of mine from a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54537453/1180620) (that I forgot about).

Comment: The TWI bus spec shows a polynomial of x^8+x^2+x+1, so it's not clear why the OP"s examples don't match this.

Comment: @Mark Adler, https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/2/27.html uses the same polynomial as you identified and references 0x18: " the XRL (exclusive OR) of the A register with the constant 18 hex is due to the presence of the EXOR feedback gates in the 1-Wire CRC after the fourth and fifth stages as shown in Figure 2". Not sure if this is coincidence.

Comment: @Mark Adler, does this explain "polynomial XOR value of 0x18"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535088/crc-implementing-a-specific-polynomial-how-does-the-polynomial-relate-to-the-po

Comment: @davegravy Yes! My long-forgotten answer there has pretty much the same code as here.